# How to work with the rows of a data frame without coercing it into a character vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
  b = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)
#   a b
# 1 0 a
# 2 1 b
# 3 0 c
# 4 1 d
```

Let's say I want to test each row for a condition and return either `"ok"` or `"not ok"`. This should work:

```
apply(df, 1, function(row){
    if (is.numeric(row[1]) & row[2] != "b") {
        "ok"
    } else {
        "not ok"
    }
})
# I should return: "ok" "not ok" "ok" "ok"
```

Unfortunately `apply` coerces the dataframe to a single type, so everything is seen as a character, so this is the output I get:

```
# "not ok" "not ok" "not ok" "not ok"
```

Is there a way to go through the rows of a dataframe preserving the data types? Maybe using `dplyr::do` or `purrr::map`?

**Update**

I know the conditions in the example don't make a lot of sense, but I was trying to simplify a more complex condition. I want to avoid using nested `ifelse` statements because they are not very readable.

Comment: Are you aware that your `is.numeric` test will be the same for every row, no matter what? Probably better to just vectorize this. e.g. `c('not ok','ok')[(is.numeric(df[[1]]) & (df[[2]] != 'b')) + 1]`

Comment: ifelse(df$b=="b", "not ok", "ok") as joran said.

Comment: I think you're really looking for `ifelse` here: `ifelse(is.numeric(df$a) & df$b != "b", "ok", "not ok")`. +1 to joran's comment about `is.numeric`... everything in a column will be the same class, but this illustrates using `ifelse` with a condition that depends on multiple columns.

Comment: @joran andrnev and Gregor Thanks for your answers, but I was looking to avoid the ifelse statement because my example is actually a simplification of a more complicated condition, which would lead to confusing nested ifelse statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `ifelse()` has been suggested in the comments and this is of course fine in your case:

```
df$c <- ifelse(is.numeric(df$a) & df$b != "b", "ok", "not ok")
 df
##   a b      c
## 1 0 a     ok
## 2 1 b not ok
## 3 0 c     ok
## 4 1 d     ok
```

But your more general question is how to apply a function over the rows of a data frame without converting it to a matrix. A possible way to do this, is to use `lapply` (or one of the others) over row indices:

```
df$c <- vapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
             if (is.numeric(df[i, 1]) & df[i, 2] != "b") {
               "ok"
             } else {
               "not ok"
             }
           }, character(1))
##  df
##   a b      c
## 1 0 a     ok
## 2 1 b not ok
## 3 0 c     ok
## 4 1 d     ok
```

Again, in your situation, `ifelse()` is just fine. But if you want to do something more complicated with the rows of your data frame, applying over row indices might be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I think the using row indices might be the best alternative to nested ifelse statements

Answer (score 1):

The first half of this answer is expanding and trying to explain @Joran's excellent comment/answer, which is mainly an exercise for me and my understanding, but hopefully it helps someone else too. (and I'm happy to have my understanding corrected).

The second half shows a couple of other non-base solutions that could be used in more complex situations.

### Joran's answer

```
c('not ok','ok')[(is.numeric(df[[1]]) & (df[[2]] != 'b')) + 1]
```

From `?data.frame`

> A data frame is a list of variables

so, each column/variable in the data.frame is a list

From ?`[`  and this question on [the difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/4002530) we note that

> For lists, one generally uses [[ to select any single element, whereas [ returns a list of the selected elements.

Therefore, using `[[` in this solution selects a single element of the the list

```
df[[1]]    ## select the 1st column as a single element (which is a vector)
# [1] 0 1 0 1
df[[2]]    ## select the 2nd column as a single element (which is a vector)
# [1] a b c d 

## note that df[1] would return the first column as a data.frame (which is a list), not a vector
## we can see that by 
# > str(df[1])
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ a: num  0 1 0 1
# > str(df[[1]])
# num [1:4] 0 1 0 1
```

With these two vectors now selected we can perform the vectorised logical check on each element within them

```
is.numeric(df[[1]]) & (df[[2]] != 'b')
# TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

From `?logical` we have

> ...with TRUE being mapped to 1L, FALSE to 0L...

so essentially `TRUE == 1L` and `FALSE == 0L`, which we can see by

```
sum(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
# [1] 3
```

Now, taking a vector of our choices

```
c("not ok", "ok")
# [1] "not ok" "ok"
```

we can use `[` again to select each element

```
c("not ok", "ok")[1]
# [1] "not ok"
c("not ok", "ok")[2]
# [1] "ok"
c("not ok", "ok")[3]
# [1] NA
## Because there isn't a 3rd element
c("not ok", "ok")[0]
# character(0)    ## empty
## and we can use a vector to select each element
c("not ok", "ok")[c(1,2,1,3)]
# [1] "not ok" "ok"     "not ok" NA
```

Which also means we can use our logical comparison from earlier to subset the choices. However, as `FALSE` is mapped to 0L, we need to add 1 to it so it will be able to select from the vector

```
c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) + 1
# [1] 2 2 1 2
```

which gives

```
c("not ok", "ok")[c(2,2,1,2)]
# [1] "ok"     "ok"     "not ok" "ok"
```

Which now gives us the information we want to include in our original `data.frame`

```
df$c <- c("not ok", "ok")[c(2,2,1,2)]
# a b      c
# 1 0 a     ok
# 2 1 b     ok
# 3 0 c not ok
# 4 1 d     ok
```

### Non-base solutions

```
## a dplyr version, still using ifelse construct
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(c = ifelse(is.numeric(a) & b != "b", "ok", "not ok")) 

## a couiple of data.table versions using by reference udpates (:=)
library(data.table)
## using an ifelse
setDT(df)[, c := ifelse(is.numeric(a) & b != "b", "ok", "not ok")]

## using filters in i
setDT(df)[is.numeric(a) & b != "b", c := "ok"][is.na(c), c := "not ok"]
```